# finding odbc error status using c++

Tags: c++, odbc

I would like to use ODBC in c++. This line of code returns -2 `(rc=-2)`. I think it is an error code, but I dont know which error?

```
rc=SQLBindParameter(hstmt,1,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE,10,0,TVPTableName,SQL_NTS,&cbTVPTableNAme);
```

I have written this block of code to extract the state, but it returns nothing:

```
void extract_error(
      char *fn,
      SQLHANDLE handle,
      SQLSMALLINT type)
  {
    SQLINTEGER i = 0;
    SQLINTEGER native;
    SQLWCHAR state[ 7 ];
    SQLWCHAR text[256];
    SQLSMALLINT len;
    SQLRETURN ret;
    fprintf(stderr,
            "\n"
            "The driver reported the following diagnostics whilst running "
            "%s\n\n",
            fn);

    do
    {
      ret = SQLGetDiagRec(type, handle, ++i, state, &native, text,
      sizeof(text), &len );
      if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
      printf("%s:%ld:%ld:%s\n", state, i, native, text);
    }
    while( ret == SQL_SUCCESS );
  }
```

Does some one know, what this code mean?

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

#include <sql.h> 
#include <sqlext.h> 
#include<sqltypes.h>




#include<exception>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>


#include "Debug\sqlncli.h";
int main()
{
    SQLHENV henv=SQL_NULL_HENV;
    SQLHDBC hdbc=SQL_NULL_HDBC;
    SQLHSTMT hstmt=SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    RETCODE rc;

   SQLWCHAR dsn[30] = L"mssqltest"; //Name DNS
   SQLWCHAR user[10] = L"di_test";
   SQLWCHAR pass[10] = L"di_test";

   SQLCHAR retValFName[256];
   SQLCHAR retValLName[256];
   SQLINTEGER cbLName,cbFName;
   SQLLEN cName=0;

   SQLCHAR *TVPTableName=(SQLCHAR *) "Person";


   SQLINTEGER Arraycode[10]={214,524,635,879,124,951,357,845,236,438};
   SQLCHAR Arrayname[10]={ 'P',  'C', 'A', 'G', 'd', 'S', 'R', 'U', 'Q'};

    SQLLEN cbTVPTableNAme,cbArraycode[10],cbArrayname[10];

   //This line is very important for working with TVP 
    // 10 is the number of values, which should be added to TVP
    rc=SQLBindParameter(hstmt,1,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE,10,0,TVPTableName,SQL_NTS,&cbTVPTableNAme);
    extract_error(" ",hstmt,SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
}
```

Comment: "Here is my complete code:" you forgot the headers.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I have updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return code for -2 is defined to `SQL_INVALID_HANDLE`. The driver can probably not get any error-information for an invalid handle.

Also, from your code you never create a valid handle, you call the `SQLBindParameter` function with a `SQL_NULL_HSTMT` handle - this cannot work.

You must first call `SQLAllocHandle` to allocate a valid statement handle (which needs a valid connection-handle, and to allocate once of those you need a valid environment handle). See here for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Besides from that, I think your function to extract the errors should work. Just pass in a valid handle.